# How to recover libudev.so.1

Tags: 16.04

By mistake, I overwrote `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1` and replaced it with a link.

You may have a look on this:

```
~$ ls /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -l | grep -i libudev
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      35 May 16 22:52 libudev.so.1 -> /usr/share/koala/koala/libudev.so.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  126840 May  5 22:25 libudev.so.1.6.4
```

How can I bring the `libudev.so.1` back?

(I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by running this command:

```
~$ sudo apt install --reinstall libudev1
```

As the result:

```
~$ ls /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -l | grep libudev
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 May  5 22:25 libudev.so.1 -> libudev.so.1.6.4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  126840 May  5 22:25 libudev.so.1.6.4
```

Comment: Hello. I got similar issue, but it won't download. It's like the same, but I'm offline. What to do now?

Comment: What is the result of `ls /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -l | grep libudev`?

Comment: Oh... Without copy option it's so frustuating to write it down... `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 16 nov 24 14:21 libudev.so -> libudev.so.1.6.5.   Lrwxrwxrwx 1 root 34 feb 27 23:01 libudev.so.1 -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.do.0` and there is third line(not important in this case...

Comment: After removing link the 2nd link is gone, but I still can't install it. No net...

Comment: BTW I am in WiFi range, but net doesnt work. Also its hard to work with no GUI...

Comment: Oh, I just solved it. Had to do `sudo ln -sf /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1.6.5 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1` and now all the stuff is working again:D

Comment: Good. Just remember: don't remove any of such files. If you remove or change anything, fist make a backup

Answer (score 1):

Try reinstalling the libudev1 package.

```
apt-get download libudev1
sudo dpkg -i libudev1_229-4ubuntu4_amd64.deb
```

or whatever the file is called.

Comment: Thanks. I used `sudo apt install --reinstall libudev1` which solved the problem.